Issues with React in cPanel
i have a react app uploaded to cPanel, in the folder "/public_html", my application works from "bun run dev" and Netlify, but when i uploaded to cPanel, i get the error 403.
When i moved my index.html and the .htaccess to the root folder, I've got a loopback error (127).
I didn't had the .htaccess, so i had to create one.
[it should be working because its only front-end app, from the blogs and the videos I've seen.]
So, I've tried almost everything online.
I've built my app with bun+vite+react+ts, done the build, the page return 403.
I thought it might be the build so i put in the parameters
 export default defineConfig({ base: "/", plugins: [react()], });
After that, without any changes, and being aware of the forbidden, i gave permission to all folders and archives.
still 403.
I changed a few times the .htaccess file, without getting any response.
I moved the .htaccess and the index.html to the root folder and then get the loopback error.
Then i looked at /etc/{domain}/ and it was clear, so my guess is, i dont have a port to do the requests, but i dont know honestly.
Feel free to ask me anything
